# adding data to database with columns continuously added

Tags: python, database, sqlite

Hello I am trying to add data to a database with sqlite3 in python. However, I am not so sure on how to write the sql code to add data to a database that continuously gets more columns. How would I write the sql code to add data to database that continuously gets more columns.

thank you for your time

Comment: Don't. Databases are designed to scale with rows, not columns. A fluid schema like this is a pain to operate on. Refactor your schema to insert more rows instead of growing columns.

Comment: I can't have reoccurring data. This is for my computing coursework and normalisation is needed to get the higher grades

Comment: Adding columns dynamically is the opposite of normalization. Please, show your use case and schema. This is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: here is why I want to add more columns. for my coursework I have to make a program to help with stock management. I have one table that stores Items and a second table that stores blueprints which require the items to be made. the middle table is the one I want to add columns to because the first column will hold the blueprint primary key data and the name for the other columns will be the primary key data from the item table. When I add an item it should create another column and blueprint should add another row however, how would i write the sql for adding a blueprint when a item is added

Comment: Create a table `blueprint_requirements` (or something like that) with three columns: `blueprint_id` (fk to blueprint), `item_id` (fk to item), and `quantity`, with a unique index over `blueprint_id` and `item_id`. For each item that the blueprint needs, insert a row into this table with the blueprint id, item id, and quantity needed. To get all the requirements for a blueprint, select from the table filtering on `blueprint_id` and joining on the items table. No dynamic schema needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To insert data you may use the cursor to execute the query. See the example from python tutorial http://www.bogotobogo.com/python/python_sqlite_connect_create_drop_table.php

```
 db.close()
 import sqlite3
 db = sqlite3.connect('data/test.db')
 cursor = db.cursor()
 cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE books(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
...                    title TEXT, author TEXT, price TEXT, year TEXT)
...                ''')
 db.commit()

 import sqlite3
 db = sqlite3.connect('data/test.db')
 cursor = db.cursor()
 title1 = 'Learning Python'
author1 = 'Mark Lutz'
price1 = '$36.19'
year1 ='Jul 6, 2013'

title2 = 'Two Scoops of Django: Best Practices For Django 1.6'
author2 = 'Daniel Greenfeld'
price2 = '$34.68'
year2 = 'Feb 1, 2014'

cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO books(title, author, price, year)
...                   VALUES(?,?,?,?)''', (title1, author1, price1, year1))

cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO books(title, author, price, year)
...                   VALUES(?,?,?,?)''', (title2, author2, price2, year2))

db.commit()
```

Maybe this would help.

Comment: thank you but how would I do the "INSERT INTO table" code if the table continually gains more columns